# How to most efficiently render picture in multiple resolutions?

Tags: opengl

Everything I render should come up in two different resolutions: One is dynamic and set according to user's window and once is constant for streaming over network.

Right now we use double PBO approach to efficiently read pixels from the GPU at the end of rendering loop. Once we get pixels we load them into a texture, scale it and read pixels back one more time.

But maybe it's possible to tell OpenGL to render picture in 2 different resolutions within the same rendering loop?

Answer (score 1):

> Right now we use double PBO approach to efficiently read pixels from the GPU at the end of rendering loop. Once we get pixels we load them into a texture, scale it and read pixels back one more time.

Worst case scenario: You're pushing the pixel data twice through the bottleneck of the peripheral bus. With PBOs you could use `glCopyBufferSubData` to transfer from a GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER to a GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER and from there into a texture. But that'd be not very elegant and leaves room for optimization.

So here's what you should actually do: Use a FBO to render into a texture, large enough to satisfy the on-screen display resolution and the stored streams aspect ratio. Say your screen display is 1920×500, but your stream was 1280×720, then you'd create a 1920×1080 texture, attach it to a FBO and render to that. Then for displaying the picture on screen you render the texture, with the top and bottom cropped in a 1:1 mapping to the main framebuffer.

For the stream you render to a 1280×720 renderbuffer attached to FBO. But careful, you have to downscale and generating mipmaps is rather slow (also the quality of glGenerateMipmaps is IMHO not the best in many implementations). So instead you should implement a proper downsampling fragment shader. You'll hardly to minify by more than a factor of 8. So your downsampling kernel will be rather simple; a fourier transform based downsampling would work as well. Using that you render to said renderbuffer and use glReadPixels (possibly through a PBO) to read back the image for streaming. To get the best performance out of glReadPixels you must specify a readback format the exactly matches the internal format of the buffer read from. Tricky for a system on screen buffer, but trivial for self defined renderbuffer.

> But maybe it's possible to tell OpenGL to render picture in 2 different resolutions within the same rendering loop?

No, not really. While recent OpenGL does support multiple viewports a primitive gets rastered always to only one viewport. Viewports are what determine the mapping from NDC space to pixel space, so they're tightly coupled to the result picture resolution.

Also there's absolutely no benefit in doing that. If it were possible it would mean that each fragment operation had to be done twice. Which would be a waste of time. It's much easier to render at a higher resolution and then to downsample the result.